# gdm3 does not start properly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gdm

Lately I finally decided to upgrade to ubuntu 18.04. After having completed the update I was not able to get any gui after login. So far I only see background and nothing else.
After many temptatives I have moved from lightdm to gdm3 but still no luck.

I created a new user and it can have a working gui, but for some reasons to me unkown it is kde instead of gnome.

More interestling I was able to get a gnome desktop after launching in a text interface the following`/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session gnome-session-flashback.target`

That is what reported in the gdm3 journalctl log (see below).
It is odd to me that gnome works if launched manually but is doesn't if launched with gdm3 (and also with lightdm).

After two days of straggling I am lost. So I beg for your help!!
Please let me know if I can provide further details.

```
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: client disconnected
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: external connection closed
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: Got timed login details for display: 0
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: client connected
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Handling new connection from outside
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDBusServer: new connection 0x55dbcf07ab80
dic 18 01:00:14 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: trying to open new session
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: display status changed: 2
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: Adding or updating utmp record for login
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: Writing wtmp session record to /var/log/wtmp
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_line :3
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_host :3
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_pid 5476
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_tv time 1545091114
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_type USER_PROCESS
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: Writing login record
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: using ut_user oslo
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Setting display device: tty5
dic 18 00:58:34 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: trying to register new display
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: session started 5476
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Emitting 'session-started' signal with pid '5476'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSession worker: watching pid 5476
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: state SESSION_STARTED
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: session opened creating reply...
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Process exit status: 0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: SHELL=/bin/bash
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: USER=oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: PWD=/home/oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: USERNAME=oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: LOGNAME=oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: RUNNING_UNDER_GDM=true
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: GROUP=oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Gdm: script environment: HOME=/home/oslo
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Running process: /etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Trying script /etc/gdm3/PreSession/Default
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: script /etc/gdm3/PreSession not found; skipping
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Trying script /etc/gdm3/PreSession
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: no script found
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: script /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default not found; skipping
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Trying script /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: script /etc/gdm3/PostLogin not found; skipping
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: Trying script /etc/gdm3/PostLogin
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: VT mode did not need to be fixed
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: first setting graphics mode to prevent flicker
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: jumping to VT 5
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: opening user session with program '/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: attempting to change state to SESSION_STARTED
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: start program: /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script  "/usr/lib/gnome-session/run-systemd-session gnome-session-flashback.target"
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: Set PAM environment variable: 'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-Flashback:GNOME'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: Set PAM environment variable: 'DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome-flashback-compiz'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: Set PAM environment variable: 'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=gnome-flashback-compiz'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm-password][5458]: GdmSessionWorker: Set PAM environment variable: 'GDMSESSION=gnome-flashback-compiz'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: type (null), program? no, seat seat0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: getting desktop names for file 'gnome-flashback-compiz.desktop'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: checking if file 'gnome-flashback-compiz.desktop' is wayland session: no
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: getting session command for file 'gnome-flashback-compiz.desktop'
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: type (null), program? no, seat seat0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Stopping all conversations except for gdm-password
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplayStore: Adding display /org/gnome/DisplayManager/Displays/94402559583056 to store
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: session id: 14
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: seat id: seat0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: session class: user
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: local: yes
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: allow timed login: yes
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: initial: no
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: session class: greeter
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: seat id: (null)
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmDisplay: id: (null)
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Setting display device: (null)
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: D-Bus server for greeters listening on unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-rTKiidoM
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Creating D-Bus server for greeters and such
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: D-Bus server for workers listening on unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-Leh2ElVX
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Creating D-Bus server for worker for session
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: session has its display server, reusing our server for another login screen
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: type (null), program? no, seat seat0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: migrated: 0
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: start or jump to session
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmManager: Will start session when ready
dic 18 00:58:33 oslo-Inspiron-N5110 gdm3[5235]: GdmSession: Emitting 'session-opened' signal
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling and reconfiguring gdm3?

Comment: Eventually I found out few packages were broken. After having fixed those packages with synaptic the problem was solved.

Comment: Since you've fixed it, it would help others with the same problem if you enter what you did to fix it below (submit an answer to your own question) and accept it.

Comment: I don't really have a precise answer. I do not remember which package I had to fix.